# Unable to mount host directory to docker container

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a python app that runs every day to download images and saves them into specified folders with each day folder creation like this `/home/ubuntu/images/yyyymmdd`.

I have built a docker container of my python app on ubuntu 20. When I try to run the app by mounting the host directory then log message prints folder created `/home/ubuntu/images/20220123` but I can not see any folder.

I have checked the docker folder `/var/lib/docker` and found that *random hash* is created inside folder `containers` and `overlay2`. So I have tried to mount with both directories as below but no luck.

```
sudo docker run -t -i -v /home/ubuntu/images:/var/lib/docker/containers --network=host testapp/img-downloader:0.0.1

sudo docker run -t -i -v /home/ubuntu/images:/var/lib/docker/overlay2 --network=host testapp/img-downloader:0.0.1
```

I can see the data folder created inside the images folder and image files got saved like this

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d52bcf61cae2e563c3c8561bab53b4bb2dd2ea2d633a14d40c96d7992fffae28/diff/home/ubuntu/images/20220123
```

What I am missing here so that it's not saving images to host directory like `/home/ubuntu/images/20220123` instead of the inside docker container.

My Dockerfile is as below -

```
FROM alpine:3.14

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3-dev mariadb-dev gcc musl-dev g++ && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python

RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ /

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

CMD [ "./main.py" ]
```

Please help here. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...What i am missing here so that its not saving images to host directory like /home/ubuntu/images/20220123 instead of inside docker container.`

Presumed you meant you want to save images to a directory on the host and not inside the container. There's no need to mount `/var/lib/docker/...`. You need to ensure your program saved files to a path that is bind mounted to the host. Examples:

`mkdir images`  # Create a directory on the host to hold the images

`docker run -it --rm -v ~/images:/images alpine ash -c "mkdir /images/yesterday; mkdir /images/today; echo 'hello' > /images/today/msg.txt; echo 'done.'"`

After the container exited, issue `ls -ld images/*` on the host will show you the 2 directories created; `cat images/today/msg.txt` will print you the content you saved via the container (simulate if you download images via the container).

Comment: As said i have created a directory and  run the above command, its works correctly . i have construted mine like this `sudo docker run -it --rm -v ~/images:~/images --network=host testapp/img-downloader:0.0.1`  and its working as expected. thanks a lot

Comment: Mark it as answer as it is working as expected.

Comment: Sure i will mark it, Could you please guide on one more thing. After downloading the images each day app read this file `testapp/assets/img_report.json`  by `testapp/testapp/upload_report.py` and modify the details and then upload to s3. But now its says no file `/assets/img_report.json`

Comment: It looks like when your program runs as the container; it assumed a directory structure on the host and not on the image? This has to do with how you copied your python project into the image. The forum observes the 1 question 1 answer rule, you can start a new question with your project directory information, more helps will come.

Comment: Sure thanks, i will google first if anyone has faced similar issue then i will post a question if not found